# How to install only free software from mini.iso?

Tags: system-installation, repository

I like to install Ubuntu from mini.iso so i'm able to choose between different desktop environments, but there is a problem; by default mini.iso doesn't give an option to install only free software; restricted and multiverse are enabled by default.

I  know it's possible to choose in expert mode, but it's a little bit tricky and i want to know if it's possible to choose install only main and universe from the normal mode.

Comment: I think you answered your own question.

Comment: Why not just disable those repos after installation?

Comment: Because i don't know how to uninstall all the packages from restricted and multiverse by a single command.

Comment: @elc79 I don't think any non-free software is installed by default.

Comment: What are those non-free software you want to exclude?

Comment: @Zacharee1 It's possible but when i see multiverse and restricted in sources.list how can i be sure of that?

Comment: @elc79 well Ubuntu can't redistribute most of that software because of legal reasons. In the normal installer, there's even an unchecked by default option to install restricted extras. Why are you so keen on avoiding it though?

Comment: If you choose the normal isos of Ubuntu, Xubuntu, etc. you have the chance to install only free software, it's an option in the boot screen, but in mini.iso there's no this option, you only can choose to install or not to install from resctricted and multiverse if you install from expert mode, and i dont know very well some parameters in expert mode.

Answer (score 5):

If you install Ubuntu from the mini.iso, I do not think you will install any non-free program packages. After rebooting into Ubuntu, you can add Universe and install the Synaptic package manager

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

and then you can use Synaptic to manage your repositories (select which ones, that you want to use). Select

**Settings -- Repositories**

[image]

and you can turn off the proprietary driver repository. You should also check the other tabs for repositories that you do not want. (I use a proprietary graphics driver, and I use non-free software for multimedia, but I can understand why you want to avoid it.)

Comment: I installed Xubuntu trough the mini.iso and when i rebooted into the system for the first time i see restricted and multiverse enabled in sources.list, can you say to me that the installer have not installed any non-free software? I don't know but when i see restricted and multiverse enable i think it's possible. Why do you have restricted and multiverse enabled by default?

Comment: There is a difference between Ubuntu and the community flavours, Xubuntu et.al. Ubuntu is strictly avoiding to install non-free software, because it can be installed in computers that are sold (part of a commercial product). The community flavours are downloaded and installed by the end users (you and me), and therefore proprietary software can be included and installed automatically. You asked about Ubuntu in the question, and the answer is about Ubuntu.

Comment: I will try to upload a capture of the expert install, the option to enable or disable restricted universe and multiverse: http://imgur.com/xWStrUH well.. i don't know how to insert a capture here, but in this link you can see the option of apt configuration in expert mode install, how can i access to this options in normal mode?

Comment: Yes, it corresponds to an option early in the GUI installer wizard `ubiquity`, to use or not to use restricted software. I would expect it to work correctly with Ubuntu. I am not sure how it works with the community flavours (if you install for example `xubuntu-desktop`). I have not used expert mode. Let us hope someone who knows will see this and answer your question.